# NHibernate mapping foreign key

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mapping, one-to-many

I have a class named TimeSheet and a class called Contract. The database table "TimeSheet" contains a foreign key "ContractOID" and the contract class contains an instance of TimeSheet as aggregation.

Now I want NHibernate to insert the OID of Contract as foreign key in my table "TimeSheet".

If Contract contained a List of TimeSheet I would realize it with an one-to-many association, but how do I handle this in that special case?

Comment: Don't you want Contract to have a one-to-many for Timesheet? I.E. wouldn't you have multiple timesheets submitted on a single contract. As I've been diving in to object modeling over the past few years, I've learned to be wary of pure 1-1 mappings (except for class hierarchy mapping). I've also learned that many-to-many doesn't exist really. That junction table has more significance than people realize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a one-to-one mapping : http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx

Comment: I already tried one-to-one mapping, but it didn´t work in my case. 

I thought there would be another way. I tried to avoid this step, but now I put the aggregation of TimeSheet into a list. 
It´s a dirty solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one-to-one mapping to me? is this correct?

See here: [NHibernate Mapping - one-to-one](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/19/nhibernate-mapping-ltone-to-onegt.aspx)

Comment: I already tried one-to-one mapping, but it didn´t work in my case. 

I thought there would be another way. I tried to avoid this step, but now I put the aggregation of TimeSheet into a list. 
It´s a dirty solution, but it works.